# Двоеточие или тире

Tags: тире-или-двоеточие

Иванов: ученый, чьи идеи рождают споры.
Иванов - ученый, чьи идеи рождают споры.
Какой вариант правильный?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможны разные синтаксические конструкции с разной семантикой.

1) **Именительный представления, или именительный темы.**

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110
https://studfiles.net/preview/2682296/

***Иванов: ученый, чьи идеи рождают споры.*** Подходит в качестве заголовка.

***Иванов...Ученый, чьи идеи рождают споры.*** Подчеркивается момент раздумья, размышления.

2) Тире **между подлежащим и составным именным сказуемым** при отсутствии связки

***Иванов – ученый, чьи идеи рождают споры.***

Для  именительного темы постановка тире нежелательна, так как парные варианты не различаются.